# Why is this shared_ptr throwing an assert when it goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, glfw

Why does the following code trigger an assert? This code initially worked and at some point started triggering an assert as the shared_ptr fell out of scope.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit()){
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLFW." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    auto window = std::shared_ptr<GLFWwindow>(glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Test", NULL, NULL));
    return 0;
}
```

I've taken just the minimum amount of code that I can to reproduce this, and maybe I misunderstand the use of shared_ptr. I've also tried it with the syntax of:

```
std::shared_ptr<GLFWwindow> window(glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Test", NULL, NULL));
```

The exact error message I am getting in the output window of the debugger (VS2013) is as follows:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Users\...\xxxx.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgdel.cpp
Line: 52

Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
```

From what I've researched it seems that it is trying to free the shared_ptr twice - is this the case and how can I prevent that? It may be worth mentioning that swapping the type from `GLFWwindow` to `struct test { int i; };` no longer triggers the assert. Does this mean that GLFWwindow is deleting the pointer internally? If so why did the code work at one point but not now?

Comment: *"why did the code work at one point but not now?"* -- Because your code exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely because `glfwCreateWindow` allocates the data using `malloc`, and `std::shared_pointer` free the memory using `delete`. Those are two different memory allocation systems, and should not be mixed.

Besides, you can't just free the pointer returned by `glfwCreateWindow`, you need to close the window properly, because you have no idea what other data may have been allocated by `glfwCreateWindow`. You need a custom delete that calls [`glfwDestroyWindow`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#gacdf43e51376051d2c091662e9fe3d7b2).

Comment: This is absolutely correct. I'll have to be more careful in the future of interacting with C APIs. Is there a preferred way of handling this in a C++ way, or will I just need to defer to GLFWwindow* to hold the pointer?

Comment: @aqez Besides taking care to have a special deleters for the different C structures, you could write a set of classes that acts as thin wrappers around the C libraries, or just don't bother and use raw pointers. IMO the second solution (making thin wrapper classes) is probably the best solution, because smart pointers aren't compatible with C functions anyway, and using raw pointers directly is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom destructor like this:

```
auto window = std::shared_ptr<GLFWwindow>(glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Test", NULL, NULL), [](GLFWWindow* window) {
   glfwDestroyWindow(window); 
});
```